# Websockets error (Signalr2 and core) when calling a DNS from a client in the same LAN that the server

Tags: websocket, url-rewriting, signalr, reverse-proxy, asp.net-core-signalr

I am developing a web application with Asp.Net Core and Signalr. The problem occurs when the client is in the same LAN that the server and it tries to reach the server using a dns. If the client uses the local ip (eg 192.168.1.40) or if the client is outside the LAN (eg a mobile) and uses the dns (eg. myapp.company.com) then it works.

The server is accessed by a reverse proxy when coming from outside by the dns following the next pipeline:

1) router with static ip: from 80 to 192.168.1.35
2) IIS site in 192.168.1.35 with ARR and Url rewrite listening the dns (myapp.company.com) and redirecting to another internal server 192.168.1.40
3) Self Hosted asp.net core app in the internal server 192.168.1.40 listening port 80 and 443

to summarize again:

It works when:
1) client inside the LAN uses the server local IP (192.168.1.40)
2) client outisde the LAN (eg. a mobile with 4g) uses the dns

It fails when:
1) client inside the Lan call the dns

Notes: I've tried with asp.net 4.7.1 and signalr 2.2.1 as well and also with two types of clients (and Unity 3d app and a javascript one) just in case it was something relating to the client.

Some years ago I think I faced the same problem and it may be related to how the reverse proxy handles the NAT resolution inside the LAN but I cannot find how I fixed neither to find a solution in internet, shame on me I didn't take notes..

At the end we can survive in production as the clients will be always outside the internal LAN but it really pisses me off and I think it can helps intranet developers. I will keep trying anyway (been searching for days) and I will post anything I find.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

take this response with a grain of salt. I just facet this with servers at home

The dns resolves to the external ip, and the router/firewall you have there does not route connections to the external ip from the inside the same way it does with external connections.

You probably either needs an internal dns entry pointing to the internal ip, or an entry in your hosts file pointing to the internal ip